# List of fields for a content type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

What im trying to do is get a list of all main fields content type has created (core fields and cck fields). Similar to what is described here: [How to list CCK fields by content type in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992134/how-to-list-cck-fields-by-content-type-in-drupal) but for Drupal 7.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to go to *Home » Administration » Reports » Field list* (`/admin/reports/fields`)?